# Adding references to libraries fails

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have projects of libraries (dlls) set up in the same solution. All get compiled well. Now I create a simple console application in the same solution to test my dlls. But adding references to any of them gives me the same error like so,

My libraries namespace e.g `VideoEditor.Frame.Engine`

```
using VideoEditor.Frame.Engine;
public static void Main(String[]args)
{
    var video=new FrameEngine("E:\\xxx.avi");
}
```

MSVS compiler complains that

> The type or namespace `VideoEditor` could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: you are missing the new key word before frame engine.

Comment: OK thanks for your spot. updated but still the error

Comment: Are their any other errors or warnings?

Comment: What version of the framework are the dlls targeting, what frameworks is the console app targeting?

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a console application in the same solution, thats good, but did you actually create a reference to the other projects?

To do this, in your new console application, right click on `References` -> `Add Reference` and then on the left tab choose `Solution` and select the library project that you are trying to access.

After this is done, the error should be gone.

Comment: I added all the references. No red highlight found in the `using...` line. But the error occurs when I build the console project.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have the using in the wrong spot...

```
using VideoEditor.Frame.Engine;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

See where it is? Should be underneath the other using statements. Don't declare it inside the class.

If thats not it, check that the build settings are the same for the library and the project you are using it in. For example, setting the library to x64 and the executable to AnyCPU may cause this error. Or if you are compiling the library for .NET 3.5 and the executable for .NET 4...

Comment: Well, my program looks exactly like yours here. I chopped off unnecessary lines in my OP.

Comment: Did you verify the build setting are identical between the projects, thats the next usual culprit.

Comment: By the way, my dll project names are like `VideoEditor.Frame` and 
`Engine` is a folder inside that project and contains class files, one of which is `FrameEngine.cs`

Comment: There should be nothing wrong with that. Did you add the reference directly to the DLL or as a project reference?

Comment: Yes, I browsed and added the Dlls directly.

Comment: Try removing it and adding a project reference instead, don't use DLL references when you can use project references, makes these problems easier to find and fix.